# Chilkat - Delphi DLL - XADES - CkXmlDSigGen_AddExternalTextRef

Tags: delphi, chilkat, xades

I have a problem using the Ck XmlDSig Gen_AddExternalTextRef function.
After signing, DigestValue always gets the same value for different URLs.

```
<ds:DigestValue>8ZRc1sGeVrPBx4lD717BgRaQekyh78QKV9SKsdt638U=</ds:DigestValue>
```

Where is the problem?

I can't find examples using the XmlDSig Gen_AddExternalTextRef function.
Thank you for your help.

Marek

Code:

```
  .......................
  CkXmlDSigGen_AddExternalTextRef(xmlSigGen,PWideChar(url1),sbXml,'utf-8', true, 'sha256','');
  CkXmlDSigGen_SetRefIdAttr(xmlSigGen,PWideChar(url1),PWideChar(ref1));

  CkXmlDSigGen_AddExternalTextRef(xmlSigGen,PWideChar(url2),sbXml,'utf-8', true, 'sha256','');
  CkXmlDSigGen_SetRefIdAttr(xmlSigGen,PWideChar(url2),PWideChar(ref2));

  ................
  CkXmlDSigGen_CreateXmlDSigSb(xmlSigGen,sbXml);
```

Resulting XML:

```
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-fc9386fa-4c0d-42ba-bd4e-7ecb61218cfd-ref1" URI="https://isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl/fhir/Encounter/131544/_history/1">
  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
  <ds:DigestValue>8ZRc1sGeVrPBx4lD717BgRaQekyh78QKV9SKsdt638U=</ds:DigestValue>

</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-fc9386fa-4c0d-42ba-bd4e-7ecb61218cfd2" URI="https://isus.ezdrowie.gov.pl/fhir/Condition/131553/_history/1">
  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
  <ds:DigestValue>8ZRc1sGeVrPBx4lD717BgRaQekyh78QKV9SKsdt638U=</ds:DigestValue>
```

Comment: function CkXmlDSigGen_AddExternalTextRef(objHandle: HCkXmlDSigGen; 
content: HCkStringBuilder;  // The content contains the non-XML data to be digested according to the charset. 

******** What does that mean? What should be entered into "CONTENT"? URI???

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for adding external text data reference(s) and then verifying:   https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/xmldsig_external_text_reference.asp